# Querying order with different polygons in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have different polygonal layers in Google Earth, on the same folder.

One layer should not be queryable, the other one yes. If the non queryable layer is visualized, I cannot query the queryable one (which is over the other one, covering the same area). I have tried to put each layer in different positions on the folder without success.

I am starting to think that I should convert the non-queryable polygon to lines. Should it be the only solution? there is no tag to say this is queryable layer or not?

And what if I want to overlay two queryable polygonal layers and query them separetely?

Answer (score 1):

Change the order, save, restart Google Earth and it will work.